# formula for the nth term of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

How do you find a formula for the nth term of this sequence?

given that $x_n$$_+$$_1$ = $x_n$ + $x_n$$_-$$_1$ (Fibonacci sequence)
and $x_0 = 1$ and $x_1 = 1$.

Do i complete the square on $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$, find the roots then the formula would be a linear combination of the roots?

I am just confused with this as usually the quadratic factors nicely but this one doesn't, thanks.

Comment: Yea you have to find the roots, which can be easily done using the quadratic formula. Seeing how the golden ratio is one of the roots, they are definitely not any simple rational numbers. If you define $r_1$ and $r_2$ to be the two roots, then the solution is written down as $x_n = c_1r_1^n + c_2r_2^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear recurrences are solved with their characteristic equation: one searches  exponential solutions $(x_n)=(r^n)$, and $r$ must satisfy the *characteristic equation*:
$$r^2=r+1\iff r=\frac{1\pm \sqrt5}2,$$
so the factorisation is $r^2-r-1=\Bigl(r-\frac{1-\sqrt 5}2\Bigr)\Bigl(r-\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2\Bigr)$.

The sequences $\;\Bigl(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\Bigr)^n$ and  $\;\Bigl(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\Bigr)^n$ are a basis of the space of solutions of the linear recurrence. The general solution is
$$u_n=\lambda\Bigl(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\Bigr)^n+\mu\Bigl(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\Bigr)^n,$$
and the coefficients $\;\lambda, \mu\;$ are determined with the initial conditions.

Comment: The maniac down-voter struck again! Funny, this down-voted+accepted answer…

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Generating functions. If you let $f(x)=\sum(c_ix^i)$ where $c_i$ is the $i-$th Fibbonaci number, you can eventually represent $f(x)$ as a Taylor series which gives the $i-$th Fibonacci number in much the same way as the method above.